# Releasing memory for array of pointers?

Tags: arrays, pointers, visual-c++, dynamic, delete-operator

I have classes Deck and PlayingCard. A Deck object must have a dynamically allocated array of pointers to PlayingCard objects:

```
PlayingCard** _playing_cards;
```

To initialise this array, the Deck's constructor and build() functions are called:

```
Deck::Deck(int size)
{
    _total_playing_cards = size;
    _deal_next = 0;
    build();
}

void Deck::build()
{
    _playing_cards = new PlayingCard*[_total_playing_cards];
    for(int i = 1; i <= _total_playing_cards; ++i)
    {
        _playing_cards[i-1] = new PlayingCard(i % 13, i % 4);
    }
}
```

Releasing the memory allocated with 'new' is handled in the destructor:

```
Deck::~Deck()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _total_playing_cards; ++i)
    {
        delete[] _playing_cards[i];
    }
    delete[] _playing_cards;
}
```

I then have a separate file, deck_test.cpp, which has a main() to simply construct and destruct a Deck object:

```
int main()
{
    Deck deck(52);
    deck.~Deck();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine, but when debugging, Visual Studio reports "Unhandled exception at 0x5ab159da (msvcr100d.dll) in Playing Cards.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2." When looking at the call stack, the problem appears to be occurring where I use the 'delete[]' operator in the 'for' loop within the destructor. Is this not the correct way to release memory from an array of pointers?

Comment: In the for loop, wouldn't a delete with no [] be sufficient, because you are deleting space for and object pointed to by _playing_cards[i]?

Answer (score 2):

Your Deck destructor needs to read as follows:

```
Deck::~Deck()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _total_playing_cards; ++i)
    {
        delete _playing_cards[i];
    }
    delete[] _playing_cards;
}
```

Note that in the loop, you have to use a non-array delete to delete a single playing card.

There is also another much bigger issue, namely that your are calling the destructor twice - once in your explicit call and the second time when deck goes out of scope at the end of `main()`. Basically you're never supposed to call a destructor on a non-heap allocated object manually in C++ as you're interfering with the built in lifetime management of C++ objects. Bad idea unless you (a) really know what you're doing and (b) you're doing it in very specific circumstances.

As an aside, using a dynamically allocated array of pointers with all the overhead that this brings is a bad idea unless you're learning about pointers and experimenting with them. In production code, please do yourself and everybody else a favour and use a std::vector instead.

Comment: Agreed about the use of vectors, but it's an academic project, so my hands are sadly tied as to what I can and can't use.

Comment: Hence the comment "unless you're learning about pointers" :). In my opinion it's a good idea to learn about them, but there are far few legitimate uses of them in modern C++ code than people have you believe.

Answer (score 1):

Please, do not call destructor directly in main().

Slightly modify the destructor code:

```
Deck::~Deck()
{
    if (_playing_cards) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _total_playing_cards; ++i) {
            delete _playing_cards[i];
            _playing_cards[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete[] _playing_cards;
        _playing_cards = NULL;
    }
}
```

By the way, why not use `std::vector<PlayingCard>`?

Comment: That won't help, you'd just be dereferencing `NULL` on the second time through the destructor.

Comment: You also don't need to set `_playing_cards[i]` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of two things:

1. you call the destructor manually, and then the destructor is called again when the variable goes out of scope. You usually shouldn't call a destructor manually unless the object was allocated with placement `new`, or you sneakily reconstruct the object with placement `new` just before it goes out of scope (but don't do that).
2. `delete[] _playing_cards[i];` should be `delete _playing_cards[i]` because `playing_cards[i]` is not an array, it's just a `new PlayingCard`.

Also, why are you doing `i = 1; i <= _total_playing_cards` in one place and `i = 0; i < _total_playing_cards` in another? It needlessly complicates things, I would advise picking one (preferably the latter) and sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call deck.~Deck(); by yourself. It will be called automatically. Just use:

```
int main()
{
    Deck deck(52);
    return 0;
}
```

And use the `delete _playing_cards[i];` in the for loop, as `delete[]` means to delete an array and `delete` means to delete only one element.